# Creating a plane composed of equilateral triangles

Tags: python, topology

Is there any straight forward method or existing python script for handling this case?  I want to make some renders of "nets" of tessellated equilateral triangles.  So far I have not found a straight forward way to achieve this.

Perhaps an existing bpy script someone has?

Comment: How do you want to control the boundaries of these nets?

Comment: If I were to write a Bpy script,  I would create a "depth" variable to iterate through how many times I would iterate through a list of outside edges and generate a new non-duplicate triangle.  so depth =1 gives me a triforce and depth 2 would tessellate more triangles on the outside edge.  When I have the mesh I could quite easily trim it to approximate a square sheet using normal methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script, you only need to change `depth` to your liking:

```
import bpy
import math

# create an equilateral triangle
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Triforce')
r = math.sqrt(3) * 0.5
mesh.from_pydata(
    [(-r, -0.5, 0.0), (r, -0.5, 0.0), (0, 1.0, 0.0)], # vertices
    [], # edges are inferred from face
    [(0, 1, 2)] # face
)

# make an object for the triangle
triangle = bpy.data.objects.new(mesh.name, mesh)
coll = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].collection
coll.objects.link(triangle)

# select the triangle edges safely
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = triangle
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
triangle.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='EDGE')

# subdiv until happiness
depth = 5
while depth > 0:
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide()
    depth -= 1

# final state: only triforce is selected
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Result from the script with `depth = 5`, `depth <= 0` gives you a single equilateral triangle.

[image]

**Edit:** Here is the script for a triangulated plane, just change `sizex` and `sizey` to your liking:

```
import bpy
import math

# create a plane of equilateral triangles
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Triforce')
r = math.sqrt(3) * 0.5

sizex = 40
sizey = 20
verts = []
faces = []
offset = 0

if sizex < 2: sizex = 2
if sizey < 2: sizey = 2

for y in range(sizey):
    if y % 2 == 0:
        offset = 0
    else:
        offset = -r
    for x in range(sizex):
        verts.append((x*2*r + offset, y*1.5, 0))

for y in range(sizey-1):
    for x in range(sizex-1):
        if y % 2 == 0:
            faces.append(((y+1)*sizex+x, y*sizex+x, (y+1)*sizex+1+x))
            faces.append((y*sizex+x, y*sizex+1+x, (y+1)*sizex+x+1))
        else:
            faces.append((y*sizex+x, y*sizex+x+1,(y+1)*sizex+x))
            faces.append(((y+1)*sizex+x, y*sizex+x+1, (y+1)*sizex+x+1))

mesh.from_pydata(
    verts, [], faces
)

# make an object for the triangles plane
plane = bpy.data.objects.new(mesh.name, mesh)
coll = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].collection
coll.objects.link(plane)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are surely a scholar and a hero

Comment: Nah, a script creating a more plane like net would be better... glad i could help.

Comment: @WhisperingShiba added a script for a plane-like triangulation, have fun.

Comment: Thats great.  I was able to just delete faces to get the result, but this is a much more principled solution.  Seeing your scripts are a very helpful resource for my learning about bpy package.